# Memorializing biblical characters through song? (Yiftach's daughter)

Tags: shoftim--book-of, yiftach

If we are going of the opinion that Yiftach did indeed kill his daughter, the verse then says the daughters of Yisroel memorialized her once a year through songs (Shoftim 11:40). Are there any other times in Tanakh where we see someone memorialized by song?

Comment: Dovid's song for Yonasan?

Comment: what perek/pasuk is that? I'd love to check it out, thanks!

Comment: @Dina see II Samuel end of chapter one. It's more of an elegy

Comment: @DoubleAA But a poetic one, at any rate

Comment: A few psalms are thanks after the psalmist was delivered and his enemy died (and the death is mentioned explicitly). Psalm 9 comes to mind specifically (according to some of its commentaries). I'm not sure whether those are included in what you're looking for, though.

Comment: Another example (although it might be stretching the definition of "song") would be Yoshiyahu, where II Divrei Hayamim 35:25 says that the elegies for his death exist "until this day as a statute for Yisrael, and are written together with the lamentations" (and (pseudo-)Rashi there says that this refers to ch. 4 of Eicha).